# Tshark export to csv

Tags: csv, wireshark, tshark

I am using the `Tshark` command to export a traffic to `csv` :

```
tshark -Y "http.response" -T fields -e  frame.number  -e http.request_in  -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport  -e http.response.code -e
```

---

```
http.response.code.desc fic.pcapng -E header=y  -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=a  >httpresponse.csv-e http.response.phrase -e http.content_type -e http.content_length -e http.location -e http.set_cookie -e http.response.line -e

frame.time -e frame.time_epoch    -r traf
```

because the one of the fields (basically `http.request.line`" has "double quote, the excel parser breaks and the output is not organized. how to remove a quote from a field before exporting it to `csv`.